# Laravel checkboxes from same group with clickable labels

Tags: laravel, checkbox, label

In Laravel, I want to show a form with checkboxes and their labels. I do it like this:

```
        {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'fancyurl', 'method' => 'post')) }}
            <p>Categories:</p>
            <ul>
                @foreach($categories as $c)
                    <li>
                        {{ Form::checkbox('categories[]', $c->id) }}
                        {{ Form::label('categories', $c->name) }}
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            <p>
                {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
            </p>
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

It shows perfectly the checkboxes and their labels. But when I click on a label, the checkbox of the label is still unchecked.
How can I set a "for"-attribute in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The for attribute of the `label` tag should be equal to the id
>   attribute of the related element to bind them together.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

You need to specify `id` attribute on checkbox:

```
{{ 
    Form::checkbox(
      'categories[]', 
      $c->id, 
      null, 
      ['id' => 'category-' . $c->id]
    ) 
}}
{{ Form::label('category-' . $c->id, $c->name) }}
```

Source: https://github.com/illuminate/html/blob/master/FormBuilder.php#L567